# How to disable zoom on mobile website for ios devices using metatag?

Tags: html, ios

I need to disable zoom on mobile website using metatag which is fixed for Android but I am searched more for ios metatag..It is not fixed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling zoom in websites through the meta tag is not possible anymore.

Safari even mentioned this in it's release notes.

> To improve accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now
>   pinch-to-zoom even when a website sets user-scalable=no in the
>   viewport.

You could try disabling with javascript though:

```
document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/gesturestart

Comment: Thank you..but What is the solution for it?

Comment: You could use something like the following: (Haven't tested, but should work) -- `document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });` Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/gesturestart

Comment: I'm sorry, but then there's no way. Been patched in Safari because of accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to disable unwanted of websites in mobile devices, thats unwanted and anouying most of the time,

then meta tag's "user-scalable=no" can get your task done

**something like this**

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).