# disable resizing my webpage on iOS - html, css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with a web page I built that in iOS, not sure what versions, but I'm testing it on the new iPhone X(and newest iOS), it's possible to kind of resize the whole webpage.

I checked other regular sites and doesn't seem possible to do that.

So i'm guessing maybe some easy CSS can do that.
It looks like this (this is not my site, just another site that's it's possible to do it with)

It does not change my actual viewing of the site, I can only drag and move it, but when I let go, it goes back to the full screen.

You can see the movie here of how it moves: https://vimeo.com/263628559

I have fixed items on the screen, so it's not any particular div that it's been done too.
[image]

Comment: Did you do fixed widths ect...? Maybe check responsive webdesign?

Comment: I don't have fixed size. It can't stay smaller or anything you just kind of move it everywhere and goes back to defulat

Comment: I added a video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable zoom on mobile website for ios devices using metatag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696420/how-to-disable-zoom-on-mobile-website-for-ios-devices-using-metatag)

Answer (score 0):

It was not that, I found a solution with jQuery

```
 $(window).bind('touchmove',
        function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
     );
```

Good luck to all :)

Comment: Using JavaScript for this isn't a good solution. The viewpoint meta tag should resolve this without JavaScript.

Comment: It's not that the screen actually changes. You can kinda pull it and move it, but when you stop it, it goes back to normal, so from what i think the viewpoint meta tag has nothing to do with it. kinda disabling the draggable option for the screen